# find checkedit control in devexpress gridcontrolrow in c#

Tags: c#, gridcontrol, devexpress-windows-ui

I have devexpress grid control in my windows form. And i have check edit control inside my grid . I need to find checkedit control at runtime from each row and based on other cell value i need to disable the checkbox if required.

Plz suggest!.

Regards & Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle the ShowingEditor event to prevent the cell from being edited.

```
private void gridView1_ShowingEditor(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
     DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView view = sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;

    if (view.FocusedColumn.FieldName == "<name of check field>" && view.GetRowCellValue(view.FocusedRowHandle, "<other field>").ToString()!="editable value"))
           e.Cancel = true;
}
```